# Which probability does method Random.next(int) work with?

Tags: java, android, random, probability

In my Android app I want to generate an integer number between 0 and 100000 using method Random.next(int). I want to know the type of probability of this method. Is it the same for every value from the range?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to draw 100000, it will broadly satisfy the statistical properties of a uniform distribution in the range [0, 100000].

That is,

1. The probability of generating any particular number is equal, and independent of the previous numbers drawn.
2. The average value of the mean of a sample of random numbers will be 100000 / 2
3. The variance of a sample will converge to the variance of a uniform distribution.

But it's not perfect, or cryptographically secure. In particular you can observe autocorrelation effects. Depending on your specific requirements you may need to consider alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to `nextInt(int)` and not `next(int)` (which is `protected`, and not public method).

It's uniform (discrete, pseudo-random) distribution.

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)):

> Returns a pseudorandom, **uniformly distributed** int value between 0
>   (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)

Answer (score 0):

It will generate a pseudorandom number. Each number has the same probability to be generated. I tried to call `Random.next(2)` 100 times and I get 50 1s and 50 0s. I think you get the idea. Its a uniform distribution.

Here's the source code if you are curious:

```
protected synchronized int next(int bits) {
    seed = (seed * multiplier + 0xbL) & ((1L << 48) - 1);
    return (int) (seed >>> (48 - bits));
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you used `next(int)` and not `nextInt(int)`? Your answer fits `nextInt()`, and the code fits `next()`.

Comment: I mean `nextInt` is just a call to `next` so whats the point of giving the source of `nextInt`? @amit

Comment: It (`nextInt()`) uses `next()`, but is not "just a call to `next()`. The code for `nextInt()` is actually in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int))

Answer (score 0):

Each call of [Random.nextInt(int value)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) will be produced different result.

### What about probability?

From docs :

> The general contract of nextInt is that one int value is pseudorandomly generated and returned. **All 2^32 possible int values are produced with (approximately) equal probability**